# return of sort function inside another function not showing result

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to understand why is not showing the result. My input is that number `120398` and what I'm trying to get as result is this: `[9,8,3,2,1,0]` sorted in descending order.

Here's my code:

```js
var number= 120398


function check(a) {
  var string= a.toString()
  var array= string.split("")
  
  
  
  var result= []
  array.forEach(function(n){
    result.push(Number(n))
  })
  
  return result.sort(function(a,b){
    return b-a
  })
  
}



check(number)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign the sorted array into some variable, e.g. `result` and reveal it using `console.log()` function.

```js
var number = 120398;

function check(a) {
  var string = a.toString();
  var array = string.split("");

  var result = [];
  array.forEach(function(n) {
    result.push(Number(n))
  })

  var result = result.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b - a
  });
  
  console.log(result);
  return result;

}

check(number)
```

It can be done in a quicker way.

```js
var number = 120398;

function check(a) {
  return (""+number).split('').map(Number).sort((a,b) => b - a);
}

console.log(check(number))
```

Comment: The function was fine, and you broke it. If you want to log function result use `console.log(check(number))` not plug `console.log` inside of it.

Comment: I prefer this answer but I understood the other one too. Thanks @dfsq

Comment: Now it's fine, but a bit clumsy, to my taste. In this case I would use log outside, but whatever.

Comment: @user2864740 You are just too quick, I've realized that throwing the whole `sort` function inside `console.log` is wrong just right after publishing the answer. Consider removing your downvote.

Comment: Might as well remove the `result` and just use `array`. The whole function body could actually be one line, except for the `console.log()` call.

Comment: ...yep, like that.

Comment: Classic answer. Btw, converting string to array can be achieved without using split methods, thanks to es2015 features: `[...String(number)]`, `Array.from(String(number))`.

Comment: @ReuvenChacha As far as I know, IE doesn't support `Array.from` so maybe it's better to leave it with old, cross-browser `split()` method (:

Comment: Just for kicks, no string conversion and purely functional: https://jsfiddle.net/br8cLpb6/ Could substitute `.concat()` for the Array spread syntax to gain legacy compatibility.

Comment: @squint It's the first time I see that kind of splitting the string. Looks scary.

Comment: No string splitting at all. Just math. Uses modulus `10` to get the rightmost digit and then divides by `10` to shift the digits over one place. Does it until you're at `0`. Here's a similar imperative example: `var n = 120398, a = []; while(n) { a.push(n % 10); n = Math.floor(n / 10); } console.log(a);`

Comment: @squint What the point of counting modulus `10` of every element, even if it returns exactly the same number? I mean, in this particular case - where elements are from 0 to 10.

Comment: The value of `n` changes inside the loop. First iteration `n` is `120398`, so modulus gives `8` and division chops off the last digit. Second iteration, `n` is `12039`, so modulus gives `9`, and so on until all the individual digits are in the Array.

Comment: I think that's usually how integers are converted to strings, or something similar anyway. Actually comes in handy every once in a while.

Comment: @squint What about performance? Is it faster than just splitting or spreading? Or it's better to stay with the 'modern' methods?

Comment: I haven't measured it, but I would be strongly inclined to say that the math approach would be much faster. Splitting requires allocating an Array and making a bunch of strings, each of which then need to be put individually through the conversion algorithm of `Number`.